# How do I know when the fading coroutine is over when fading out or in?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fading : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Fading")]
    public List<GameObject> objectsToFade = new List<GameObject>();
    public float duration;
    public Coroutine fadeCoroutine;
    public bool automatic = false;
    public bool startFading = false;
    [Header("Random")]
    public bool randomObjects = false;
    public bool randomDuration = false;
    public bool faded = false;

    private bool fadeInOut = false;
    private bool coroutineIsRunning = false;
    private List<Material> objectsToFadeMaterials = new List<Material>();
    private bool randomOnce = false;
    private Material randomMaterial;
    private float originalDuration;

    private void Start()
    {
        originalDuration = duration;

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToFade.Count; i++)
        {
            objectsToFadeMaterials.Add(objectsToFade[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (startFading)
        {
            if (automatic)
            {
                if (!coroutineIsRunning)
                {
                    Fade();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
                {
                    Fade();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Fade()
    {
        fadeInOut = !fadeInOut;

        if (fadeCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(fadeCoroutine);

        if(randomDuration)
        {
            duration = Random.Range(1, 20);
        }
        else
        {
            duration = originalDuration;
        }

        if (randomObjects && objectsToFade.Count > 1)
        {
            if (randomOnce == false)
            {
                randomMaterial = objectsToFadeMaterials[Random.Range(0, objectsToFadeMaterials.Count)];
                randomOnce = true;
            }
            if (fadeInOut)
            {
                fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(randomMaterial, 0, duration));
            }
            else
            {
                fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(randomMaterial, 1, duration));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToFadeMaterials.Count; i++)
            {
                if (fadeInOut)
                {
                    fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(objectsToFadeMaterials[i], 0, duration));
                }
                else
                {
                    fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(objectsToFadeMaterials[i], 1, duration));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        float t = 0;

        coroutineIsRunning = true;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            material.color = color;

            if(t > duration)
            {
                coroutineIsRunning = false;
            }

            if(color.a == 1)
            {
                randomOnce = false;
            }

            if(color.a == 0)
            {
                faded = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that if the color.a is 0 then the object faded out finished then I set faded to true.

In the second script that is attached to a teleporter I want to start teleporting if the object faded out then teleport to the next teleporter and fade in back and so on.

This script is attached to each teleporter :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Fading fading;
    public List<GameObject> objectsToTeleport = new List<GameObject>();

    //Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectsToTeleport = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ObjectToTeleport").ToList();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        StartCoroutine(fading.FadeTo(objectsToTeleport[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 0, 2));
    }
}
```

and this script is the teleporting script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> objectsToTeleport;
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> currentlyTeleportedObjects;
    public List<GameObject> teleporters;
    public float teleportingTime;
    public float teleportingStartTime;
    public bool startTeleporting = false;
    public GameObject[] groups;
    public bool loop = false;
    public bool random = false;
    public int teleportationsCount = 0;

    [Serializable]
    public class ObjectToTeleport
    {
        public GameObject teleportableObject;
        public int teleportOrder;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        StartTeleporting();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void StartTeleporting()
    {
        if (startTeleporting)
        {
            if (teleporters.Count > 1 && objectsToTeleport.Count > 0)
            {
                InvokeRepeating("MoveTeleportableObjects", teleportingStartTime, teleportingTime);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveTeleportableObjects()
    {
        if (teleportationsCount < objectsToTeleport.Count)
            currentlyTeleportedObjects.Add(objectsToTeleport[teleportationsCount]);

        for (int i = 0; i < currentlyTeleportedObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!loop)
            {
                MoveObjects(i);
            }
            else
            {
                MoveObjects(i);
            }
        }
        teleportationsCount++;
    }

    private void MoveObjects(int i)
    {           
        GameObject destinationTeleporter = teleporters[currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder];
        currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportableObject.transform.position = destinationTeleporter.transform.position;
        if (currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder < teleporters.Count - 1)
        {
            currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder++;
        }
        else if (loop == true)
        {
            {
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need somehow a synchronization between the fading and the teleporting in the Teleport script.
But it seems a bit complicated.

The Fading script on it's own and the Teleporting script on it's own are working fine but making a synchronization between them is the problem.

Update :

What I tried :

In the Fading script I added two methods FadIn and FadeOut and calling the FadeOut in the Teleport script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fading : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Fading")]
    public List<GameObject> objectsToFade = new List<GameObject>();
    public float duration;
    public Coroutine fadeCoroutine;
    public bool automatic = false;
    public bool startFading = false;
    [Header("Random")]
    public bool randomObjects = false;
    public bool randomDuration = false;
    public bool faded = false;

    private bool fadeInOut = false;
    private bool coroutineIsRunning = false;
    private List<Material> objectsToFadeMaterials = new List<Material>();
    private bool randomOnce = false;
    private Material randomMaterial;
    private float originalDuration;

    private void Start()
    {
        originalDuration = duration;

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToFade.Count; i++)
        {
            objectsToFadeMaterials.Add(objectsToFade[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (startFading)
        {
            if (automatic)
            {
                if (!coroutineIsRunning)
                {
                    Fade();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
                {
                    Fade();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Fade()
    {
        fadeInOut = !fadeInOut;

        if (fadeCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(fadeCoroutine);

        if(randomDuration)
        {
            duration = Random.Range(1, 20);
        }
        else
        {
            duration = originalDuration;
        }

        if (randomObjects && objectsToFade.Count > 1)
        {
            if (randomOnce == false)
            {
                randomMaterial = objectsToFadeMaterials[Random.Range(0, objectsToFadeMaterials.Count)];
                randomOnce = true;
            }
            if (fadeInOut)
            {
                fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(randomMaterial, 0, duration));
            }
            else
            {
                fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(randomMaterial, 1, duration));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToFadeMaterials.Count; i++)
            {
                if (fadeInOut)
                {
                    fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(objectsToFadeMaterials[i], 0, duration));
                }
                else
                {
                    fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(objectsToFadeMaterials[i], 1, duration));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        float t = 0;

        coroutineIsRunning = true;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            material.color = color;

            if(t > duration)
            {
                coroutineIsRunning = false;
            }

            if(color.a == 1)
            {
                randomOnce = false;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeIn(Material material, float duration)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, 1, duration));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeOut(Material material, float duration)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, 0, duration));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    }
}
```

In the Teleport script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Fading fading;
    public List<GameObject> objectsToTeleport = new List<GameObject>();

    //Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectsToTeleport = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ObjectToTeleport").ToList();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        StartCoroutine(fading.FadeOut(objectsToTeleport[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 3));
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        
    }
}
```

How do I continue from here ? what should I do next ?

Comment: Why does no one ever pass a method as a parameter to be called when it’s over?

Comment: @BugFinder how do you know in the ontriggerenter if the fade out or in is over ? I added two methods fadein and fadeout updated my question.

Comment: I know now when the fading out or in is finished but how do I know it in the ontriggerenter in the Teleport script ? There is no loop or something in the ontriggerenter event so how do I know when the fading is finished ? I know in the coroutine it self when it finished but I need to know it also in the ontriggerenter.

Comment: Or do you just need it to continue with doing the teleport when the coroutine is done? If so you could yield until the routine stops and then do the teleport or like I suggested pass a method as the method to run on completion

Comment: @BugFinder right I need it to continue doing the teleport when the fading is end.  the idea is to make that when one object enter the trigger start fade out make a teleport then fade in in then exit teleporter and so on then the next object enter the trigger and same logic.

Comment: So have you tried passing a method then ?

Comment: @BugFinder yes like in the derHugo answer but I'm not sure how to continue with the Teleporting script now in the Teleport script.

Comment: Well if you passed a method. At the end of the fade call the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

#### Simply yield the routine

You already have both as Coroutines so you could wrap them in another Coroutine and `yield return` it instead of `StartCoroutine` (this is something you should do in `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` anyway!)

```
// If this returns IEnumerator Unity automatically runs it as Coroutine
private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    yield return fading.FadeOut(objectsToTeleport[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 3));

    // Something after fading finished
    Debug.Log("Fade Out finished!");
}
```

You could of course as well have them separately like

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    StartCorouine (EnterRoutine(other));
}

private IEnumerator EnterRoutine ()
{
    yield return fading.FadeOut(objectsToTeleport[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 3));

    // Something after fading finished
    Debug.Log("Fade Out finished!");
}
```

---

#### Callback

Another way would be passing in a callback that is executed once the routine finishes like e.g.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    StartCoroutine(fading.FadeOut(objectsToTeleport[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 3, OnFadeOutFinished));
}

private void OnFadeOutFinished ()
{
    Debug.Log("Fade Out finished!", this);
}
```

or using a lambda, especially helpful if you want to do something with the `other` reference

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    StartCoroutine(fading.FadeOut(objectsToTeleport[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 3, () => {
        Debug.Log("Fade Out finished!");  
    }));
}
```

and have it as parameter in your routine like

```
private IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration, Action callback)
{
    Color color = material.color;
    float startOpacity = color.a;

    float t = 0;

    coroutineIsRunning = true;

    while (t < duration)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

        color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

        material.color = color;

        if(t > duration)
        {
            coroutineIsRunning = false;
        }

        if(color.a == 1)
        {
            randomOnce = false;
        }

        yield return null;
    }

    callback?.Invoke();
}

public IEnumerator FadeIn(Material material, float duration, Action callback = null)
{
    yield return FadeTo(material, 1, duration, callback));
}

public IEnumerator FadeOut(Material material, float duration, Action callback = null)
{
    yield return FadeTo(material, 0, duration, callback));
}
```

Comment: if I'm using the lambda way when it finished fade out I'm changing the object to teleport to the next teleporter position then I start the fadein coroutine the problem is that it's trying to make the fadeout again because the fadein make it collide again.

Comment: @RonLipman during the entire process you could disable the collider and only enable it at the very end

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but I personally in this case would create new coroutines `FadeIn` and `FadeOut`, instead of directly calling the following:

`fadeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FadeTo(objectsToFadeMaterials[i], 0, duration));`

Then, at the end of your `FadeOut` coroutine you can take some additional step(s) to trigger a teleport or whatever else you need to trigger. It looks like you don't want your `Fading` to hold a reference to your `Teleporting`, which is smart, so you could choose to fire an event instead that your `Teleporting` component can subscribe to.

Comment: In the script Teleport to create two methods FadeIn and FadeOut instead reference to the Fading.  Ok did it.

Comment: No, those methods `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` would most likely need to be in your `Fading`object, they're just wrappers to `FadeTo` that will also let you do some additional actions aftwerward.